# Run a bash script inside a for loop and take variable value from for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash code that takes input file, process it and shows output files. However, I want the code to run on all particular extension (.wfx) files in a directory. Suppose I have 1,2,3.....100.wfx files (100 .wfx files) and I want to obtain the output in one go.
The original bash script (cutting short a lot of greps,awk and seds) looks like this,

```
system_name="1"
wfxfile=${system_name}.wfx
.
.
.
echo "id1 id2 " > ${system_name}_energies.txt
```

Since the above code runs well, I do not want to change it. The name of the script is  extract_value.sh. I was thinking if I can feed the variable "system_name" as input file names with a for loop, I can achieve the goal. So I changed the script very little,

```
system_name="$i"
wfxfile=${system_name}.wfx
```

I was trying things like,

```
for i in *.wfx; do system_name="{$i}"; echo $system_name; ./extract_value.sh;done
```

What I am getting is this,

```
10_1.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
10_2.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
10.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
11_1.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
11_2.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
1_1.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
11.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
12_1.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
12_2.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
1_2.wfx
grep: .wfx: No such file or directory
```

The problem definitely looks like improper use of variable in a loop. However, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either `export` the variable from the outer shell to make it visible in the environment of the shell process you run; or pass it as a command line argument. Shell variables that aren't exported are only visible inside the same shell instance.

E.g. mytest.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "cmdline arg: '$1', envvar: '$sysname'"
```

and then:

```
for i in abc def ghi; do
    export sysname="$i"
    ./mytest.sh "$i"
done
```

You could also just use `sysname="$1" ./mytest.sh` to have the `sysname` variable passed to the environment of the inner script *without* setting it in the outer shell.

Comment: Can this analogy be used to change variable to other python or fortran scripts? Instead of using ./mytest.sh, use python3 mytest.py?

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay, a Python script will get the environment variables and command line arguments the same way as a shell script, you'll just have to figure out the way to access them inside Python. `sys.argv` and `os.environ`

Answer (score 1):

Since you made a small change to the script, may I suggest another?

Change the line

```
system_name="$i"
```

to

```
system_name="$1"
```

then make the loop

```
for i in *.wfx; do
    [[ ! -f "${i}" ]] && break
    ./extract_value.sh "${i}"
done
```

The `-f` check is for the case where there are no such files: the shell will set i to `*.wfx` literally. The core change in the loop and in the script is to pass the file name and accept it as the first positional argument.